# Detect image change from vp9 encoder (libvpx library)

Tags: image, video, encoding, fullscreen, video-processing

I am using libvpx library for my screen sharing project where I used vp9 encoder along with svc technique to encode video and later decode it. I first capture the screen data (RGB) using third party library and save it in a large array and then use the encoder.

Now I need to detect whether the newly provided image to the encoder is the same as previous, does the encoder even able to detect it? if so then how ?

I am planning to skip encoding or sending in that case as in adverse network condition this makes the previously renderred good static image in the receiver side bad eventually for no reason. I also have plan for other things with this. I know I can use variable kf distance but for some reason its not working and I want to avoid scanning the whole 1920*1080 array to check manually with the previous when the encoder already does this under the hood anyway for processing.

Answer (score 1):

It would be overkill to modify (and recompile) the libVPX source code just to know if two images are the same pixel values.

> *"I need to detect whether the newly provided image to the encoder is the same as previous, does the encoder even able to detect it? if so then how?"*

- There is a function: [**compare_img** from `tools_common.c`](https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/blob/b759032a0ed2b57ea3412f6820eda377a2dad480/tools_common.c#L556).
- There is a function: [**find_mismatch** from `tools_common.c`](https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/blob/b759032a0ed2b57ea3412f6820eda377a2dad480/tools_common.c#L689)
- Check also the associated [`tools_common.h`](https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/blob/b759032a0ed2b57ea3412f6820eda377a2dad480/tools_common.h#L183).

The `compare_img` function will `return match;` where *match* is an integer.

for example (in pseudo-code):

```
#include "./tools_common.h" //this has the function: compare_img

int myResult = compare_img( &img_A, &img_B );

if ( myResult != 1 )
{
    //# handle not matching
}
```

Investigate these functions (their expected inputs, what the output integer means, etc) and be sure you can correctly give them their expected data. You should be able to call them directly (thus skipping the need for creating your own check with a `For` loop)

**Possible solution:**
The best you can do here is **halve the image size** before comparing (or go lower like 1/4 instead 1/2). This way you fit the scanning of two images (@ `960 x 540`) to become the same cost as that of scanning one image @ `1920 x 1080`.

- Check also if there is a chance to use GPU to compare large pixels.
- Check if a "fast" library exists to compare two arrays as quickly as possible for the user CPU.

Otherwise start calling some function(s) included inside LibVPX like `compare_img`.

The function's result can recreated with (pseudo-code):

```
int pos = 0;
int result = 0; //# will be -1 if not matching, and 1 if matching
int arrayLength = (1920 * 1080) * 3; // #or use * 4 if you got Alpha channel

int[] myRGB_img_A; //image 1 array
int[] myRGB_img_B; //image 2 array

while( pos < arrayLength)
{
    //# if at end of array then assume all pixels are matching
    if( pos == (arrayLength-1) ) { result = 1; break; }
    
    if( myRGB_img_A[ pos ] != myRGB_img_B[ pos ] )
    {
        std::cout << "Images are not equal..." << std::endl;
        result = -1; break;
    }
    
    pos++;
}

//# Now check result after While loop breaks
std::cout << "Result is: " << result << std::endl;
```

If using alpha channel in your RGB (so it is really RGBA or ARGB) then you'll get a 32bit integer so you can just use `sizeof(uint_32_t)` to read 4 array slots at one time as a single integer.